# Iteratively generate a template containing handlebars (spacebars)

Tags: templates, meteor, spacebars

So to keep it simple, the final template needs to look like this:

```
<template name="Profile">
  <h1> This is a profile view </h1>
  <h4>Username</h4>
  <p>{{username}}</p>
  <h4>Name</h4>
  <p>{{name}}</p>
  <h4>Email:</h4>
  <p>{{email}}</p>
</template>
```

And the corresponding helpers are as below:

```
Template.Profile.helpers({
  username: function() {
    return this.username;
  },
  email: function() {
    return this.emails[0].address;
  },
  name: function() {
    return this.profile.name;
  }
});
```

Now, this template will keep on growing as new fields are added and in an attempt to keep the code clean I tried splitting up the templates into two as shown below:

```
<template name="Profile">
  <h1> This is a profile view </h1>
  {{#each items}}
    {{> Section}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="Section">
  <h4>{{label}}</h4>
  <p>{{ {{id}} }}</p>
</template>
```

And the new template has this corresponding helper:

```
Template.Section.helpers({
  items: function() {
    var fields = [
      {label: "Username", id="username"},
      {label: "First Name", id="name"},
      {label: "Email Address", id="email"}
    ];
    return fields;
  }
});
```

The main thing is that bit in the `Sections` template where I'm trying to nest the Spacebars somehow: `<p>{{ {{id}} }}</p>`

The effect I'm trying for is that the sections are all iteratively composed into the `Profile` template which then sees `{{name}}` or `{{email}}` and then that `Profile` helper fills in the field.

Is this even possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is pretty close - you just need to return an array of reactive data from your helper. Give this a try:

```js
Template.Profile.helpers({
  sections: function() {
    return [
      {label: 'username', data: this.username},
      {label: 'email', data: this.emails[0].address},
      {label: 'name', data: this.profile.name}
    ];
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="Profile">
  <h1>This is a profile view</h1>
  {{#each sections}}
    {{> section}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="section">
  <h4>{{label}}</h4>
  <p>{{data}}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks :) Just for comparison, any thoughts on whether it's possible to implement this using Template.parentData()?

Comment: I suppose you could do that, but it strikes me as more awkward for two reasons: (1) I like to have my templates be as independent as possible for maintainability and reusability - any time you mix your concerns by accessing another template's data you lose some of both (granted, sometimes it's necessary). (2) If the parent held the user, you'd still either have to pass a path within the user object to each sub-template, or each sub-template would know how to access the value based on a label - this feels unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: fair enough... anyway the original solution worked brilliantly. :)